# What are proper values for SITE_NAME configuration in Django settings?

Tags: python, django, config, edx

I'm working on [edx-platform](https://github.com/edx/edx-platform) which is an opensource MOOC platform that is based on Django 1.4.

I'm improving the translation of it and it keeps bother me that the default (and required) value for `SITE_NAME` is `edx.org`. While I can change it to my domain e.g. `edraak.org` I still don't like having the `SITE_NAME` to be a domain.

It seems that even the vanilla Django [expects it to be a domain name](https://github.com/django/django/search?l=python&q=site_name&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Is that an [old naming issue](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)? or is it something I'm misunderstanding.

Could you please explain what are the proper (i.e. expected/recommended by Django) for this setting value?

Comment: `SITE_NAME` is not a setting used by Django itself. The github search only reveals a variable in a test that uses that name, not a Django setting.

Comment: The `SITE_NAME` should be a domain name as django uses it to contract the `Site` objects that are used to navigate between pages. The default value for this is `example.com` in django. So when you create absolute urls, this domain will be used along with any relative paths.

Comment: @kicker86 none of that is true at all. Django doesn't construct Site objects from a setting, and it absolutely does not use Site objects for page navigation.

Comment: I should have specified that Site objects are used in views. See here for how django uses the Site framework for things like redirects and explicitly setting the site in case of multiple sites being configured in django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sites/#how-django-uses-the-sites-framework